# Can't build project "Add instance declaration"

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~panitz/hopengl/skript.html#perspective), and compiler returns this error when i am trying to build the project

```
No instance for (Fractional (GLdouble -> GLdouble))
  arising from a use of `keyboard'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Fractional (GLdouble -> GLdouble))
In the first argument of `Just', namely `(keyboard pPos)'
In the second argument of `($=)', namely `Just (keyboard pPos)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  keyboardMouseCallback $= Just (keyboard pPos)
```

Here is the code

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT  as GLUT
import Squares
import OrbitingPointOfView
import ColorCube
import Data.IORef

main = do
    (progName,_) <-  getArgsAndInitialize
    initialDisplayMode $= [WithDepthBuffer,DoubleBuffered]
    createWindow progName
    depthFunc $= Just Less

    pPos <- newIORef (90::Int, 270::Int, 2)
    keyboardMouseCallback $= Just (keyboard pPos) -- <---  causes the problem

    displayCallback $= display pPos
    reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
    mainLoop

display pPos = do
    loadIdentity
    setPointOfView pPos
    clear [ColorBuffer,DepthBuffer]
    colorCube 1
    swapBuffers

keyboard pPos c _  _ _ = keyForPos pPos c
```

Guide me how to solve this problem ...

Comment: All the code you posted seems to be correct. Based on the tutorial you linked, I would assume your error is somewhere in the `keyForPos` or `modPos` functions.

Comment: thanks, a lot, really, i passed wrong number of arguments to modPos function.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error message of the form

```
No instance for (... (... -> ...))
```

where the type without an instance is a function type (as the -> shows),
then usually the problem is that a function has been applied to the wrong
number of arguments somewhere.

However as @user2407038 said, it's not clear from your code where that happens, as it depends on the types of functions not defined in what you pasted.
As a guess, perhaps you should give a different number of arguments to either
keyboard or keyForPos.